# Combining frequencies

Tags: matlab, audio, click, frequency

I am designing a sound signal in MATLAB that is composed of certain (10-12) frequencies. Each frequency tone is of 1 ms duration. When I am changing between frequencies, the change is abrupt and creating unwanted click sounds. The orange triangle in the image shows the change of frequencies:

[image: change of frequencies]

How do I transition from one frequency to another? Currently I am just appending tones together.

```
Time = (0: ToneDur * Fs)/Fs;
Sound = zeros(1,100000);  % Zero padding
for i = 1 : TotalFreq
    Tone = Amp(i).*cos(2 * pi * Frequency(i) * Time);
    Sound = [Sound, Tone];
end
```

Comment: Use an exact number of periods for each piece. That way they will transition nicely without the abrupt change.

Comment: Hi Cris, how would I do that for say a frequency at 10k and the next at 12k?

Comment: I am using Matlab.

Comment: @farhad: I did not see your question till now. If you add a `@` before the name, the user will be notified. See at the bottom here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting — the answer you have now explains what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method will be just to generate only whole periods of a given frequency.
You will first need to create an array of the frequencies to be generated then calculate
the [linear period](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9e/Commutative_diagram_of_harmonic_wave_properties.svg/1200px-Commutative_diagram_of_harmonic_wave_properties.svg.png) in samples. With a given duration you can the calculate how many
periods of the wave can fit in the given time duration. For frequencies with partial
periods, simply round the number of periods. This will mean that not all frequency truly
play to the same period of time but the difference should not be enough to actually notice, especially for higher frequencies.

Using the coding convention of your question, this will do the trick

```
Fs = 44100; % sampling rate
ToneDur = 0.15; % duration of tone in seconds
Frequency = [1:0.5:12] * 100;  % array of frequencies (100hz - 12khz in 50Hz steps)
TotalFreq = length(Frequency); % the number of frequencies

freqLengths = (1 ./ Frequency) * Fs; % wave period in samples
numberOfPeriodsPerFreq = Fs * ToneDur ./ freqLengths
sampDur = floor(numberOfPeriodsPerFreq) .* freqLengths % array number of samples required per frequency for a whole number of periods

Sound = 0; % instantiate variable to store audio data

for i = 1 : TotalFreq
  Tone = sin(2 * pi * Frequency(i) * [0:sampDur(i)]/Fs);
  Sound = [Sound , Tone];
end

soundsc(Sound, Fs) % play audio
```

Comment: @Cris - It does the job for me but I was trying to put the parts together and I didn`t really get how you came up with the numberofperiods formula. The link you provided for linear period showed its related with the wavelength as x/v so shouldnt the freqLengths part be in the numerator.

Comment: @farhad - the wave period `T` (time taken for one cycle) of a tone `f` is `T = 1/f`. To express `T` in samples, multiply by sampling rate `Fs` ( `freqLengths = T*Fs` ). `freqLengths` is now the wave period in samples of each tone. `numberOfPeriodsPerFreq` is then the duration of each tone in samples, `Fs * Ts`, divided by the wave period for each tone in samples. Some of `numberOfPeriodsPerFreq` will not be whole numbers and that is why there are clicks. `sampDur` truncates the time that each tone plays in order that they last for whole periods. Does that help to clear things up?